# Vineet Reynolds / java-ee-6-galleria project running with MySQL instead of Derby

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to follow / learn more about Java EE and have found a very nice article http://blog.eisele.net/2012/03/java-ee-6-running-galleria-on-glassfish.html which is a step-by-step guide of how to running it on Glassfish. The original source code can be found at "hg clone https://bitbucket.org/VineetReynolds/java-ee-6-galleria"

However, now I would like to change the Derby database to MySQL and Eclipselink since i am more familiar with it. I have succeed to run the *IntegrationTest(s) but not unit tests RepositoryTest(s).

I have changed the persistence-test.xml file to:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

  <persistence-unit name="galleria-ejb" transaction-type="JTA">  

  <!-- <persistence-unit name="galleria-ejb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> -->
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/galleriaDS</jta-data-source> <!-- Added -->

    <class>info.galleria.domain.Album</class>
    <class>info.galleria.domain.Group</class>
    <class>info.galleria.domain.Photo</class>
    <class>info.galleria.domain.User</class>

    <properties>        
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />        
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />  

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When I run the mvn clean test -Dtest=AlbumRepositoryTest#testCreateNewAlbum I got the following:

> EL Info]: 2013-02-15
>   23:20:16.615--ServerSession(4248874)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink,
>   version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
>   org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410001: Connection failure:
>   socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid:
>   OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
>     at $Proxy32.connectFailure(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:270)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:129)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:393)
>     at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)     at
>   org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1241)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:411)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:654)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
>     at
>   info.galleria.service.jpa.AbstractRepositoryTest.setUp(AbstractRepositoryTest.java:88)
>     at
>   info.galleria.service.jpa.AlbumRepositoryTest.setUp(AlbumRepositoryTest.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:48)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:340)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:242)
>     ... 58 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>     at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:364)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:356)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:623)  at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:325)
>     ... 59 more

So my real question is: Is there anybody out there that can show me how to run the Vineet Reynolds / java-ee-6-galleria project with mysql instead of derby? Hibernate or Eclipselink does not really matter, I just want to run mysql instead of derby =)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.. silly mistake, just started from scratch and it fixed the problem..